# Can't connect to ProtonVPN using CLI?

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager, vpn

I can't connect to ProtonVPN using its official client from **pypi** on my `Ubuntu 20.04` but on the same WiFi and using the same DNS (`8.8.8.8`) and its android app I can seamlessly connect.
I don't have a clue where the underlying problem might be.

The errors it gives me is as follows:

```
[!] There was an error connecting to the ProtonVPN API.
[!] Please make sure your connection is working properly!
```

Comment: did you try this https://github.com/ProtonVPN/linux-cli/issues/97#issuecomment-631997539 ? (seems to be working for me - on Ubuntu 20.10)

Comment: @jjrr no it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

If you are stuck after downgrading, it probably still reads from protonvpn config file.

I had to change the `api_domain` in `~/.pvpn-cli/pvpn-cli.cfg` to `api_domain = https://api.protonmail.ch` and now it's working.